# Android unique id assigning

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have an Android application where users can connect and disconnect to/from a server. I don't want to have any kind of registration in app, but I want server to recognize users that have already been connected to the server. One way to do this might be using Google Play services and [Instance id API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/) by sending the id generated by gcm to the server each time client connects. Using Google Play services API I also get a way to implement push notifications quite easily. However, I don't feel that I will need them, and I will also have to implement ios and web clients later. Afaik there is no available Google Play services API for web so this raises the question: what other alternatives might be?

Answer (score 1):

The way I have understood the question is, you want a uniqueId which is unique for every device and you don't want the registration id which we get from GCM.
So you have a device Id which is unique for every device and there is a way of getting the device ID

```
public String uniqueId() {
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
        tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
        tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
        androidId = ""
                + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
                        mContext.getContentResolver(),
                        android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(),
                ((long) tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
        String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();

        return deviceId;
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use this method for iOS devices as well as for Web clients.